# JS рекурсивный вывод чисел от 1 до N

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Мне нужно вывести числа от 1 до N через рекурсию. Мой код в целом рабочий, но мне он кажется достаточно костыльным, а самая главная проблема-он выводит числа в обратном порядке. Как это можно переработать? Вот мое решение:

```js
function numberOutput(n) {
    return (n > 1) ? n.toString() + numberOutput(n - 1) : 1;
}
console.log(numberOutput(9));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function numberOutput(n) {
  return n ? numberOutput(n - 1) + n.toString() : "";
}
console.log(numberOutput(9));
```